# Gap between Travel and Expatriates

Tags: discussion, scope, expat-questions, stackexchange

Regarding this question: [UK student visitor visa refused, Erasmus Mundus scholarship](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52695/uk-student-visitor-visa-refused-erasmus-mundus-scholarship).

This was closed on Travel, since as a rule questions about studying abroad are off topic, and recommended posting on Expatriates. When [the same question was posted on Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/6737/uk-student-visitor-visa-refused-erasmus-mundus-scholarship) it was flagged as being too short term, apparently driven by a guideline of "long term visas of a year or more".

Can we coordinate with Expatriates so that a question like this is on-topic at one or the other of our sites?

Comment: There's a [related discussion on the Expats meta](http://meta.expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/260/are-questions-about-studying-abroad-where-the-duration-is-only-one-term-semester)

Comment: Would someone of that visa be allowed access to NHS?

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee [Apparently not](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/iss/immigration-visa/student-visitor-visa).

Comment: People who study abroad are still able to travel. The question was actually **about** visa denial/refusal/rejection, which we deal with here pretty well so I voted to reopen it.

Comment: my opinion is that travel and expats should be merged into one site, I know many will disagree.  I never visit the expat site because I can't be bothered checking two sites, and travel has more relevant stuff most of the time.  SO is about "programming" and has many tags that may be completely irrelevant for some people i.e. a C# developer will usually not look at any PHP or IOS related tags.  I don't see how expat questions are any different

Comment: @EdmundYeung99 I would tend to agree with you, but the problem lies in what the site name implies. "Stackoverflow" is is tech neutral name. Travel and Expats aren't so, each seems (via connotation) to cater to different needs of people. If Travel.SE was renamed to "PackYourBags" and we all "knew" that it was about **everything** related to moving from one country to another (whether for visit or immigration) then sure it could all be one site.

Comment: @unknownprotocol But the underlying point I'm trying to make is that the word travel is about everything (tourism, study, research, work, immigration etc). The word does not limit itself to any particular reason or duration for movement. Take a look at the wiki page for travel: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travel

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to take this up from a purely technical point of view.

When we get a UK refusal, we like to make the OP insert their refusal formulae.  This is a formal notice from the UK government that explains the decision.

Without going in to speed codes and the mechanics of why the text is useful, we can turn to the relevant text for DJClayworth's question above...

> I am therefore not satisfied that your application meets the paragraph
>   **A57D(b)**

We'll forgive the OP for her mild transcription error and focus on the **A57D(b)** part of the sentence.

We observe that refusals falling within TSE's domain cite **Appendix V** of the rules (like when you see *V 4.2(a)* for the reason).  Those questions belong to us because Appendix V contains the **visitor rules**, which is our turf.

Paragraph A57D is in [Part 3 of the rules](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/423564/20150424_immigration_rules_part_3_final.pdf), which deals with short-term students.  Different underlying principles, different assumptions, different semantics, different topology from visitors.  Moreover, there is no terminology in the rules where 'short-term' is applied to visitors other than a short-term worker replacement and then it is to explain that a short-term worker replacement is ***forbidden***.  'Short-term' is used exclusively for students and workers.

So by all rights and privileges when a strict technical standard is applied the question belongs to Expats.

The ECO said she was a *student*.  We get visitors, Expats gets students.  Trying to carve it out by visa duration will get unbearably murky.

### Denouement

The OP resubmitted her application before anyone answered her question.  She got some help in the chat room for her cover letter etc. I was advising her to take a week and get a consultation/doc check before resubmitting, but it was too late.  Refusals are emotive and back-to-back applications can often make matters worse.  I doubt that answers from either TSE or Expats would have changed the outlook significantly, but perhaps her cover letter will carry the day.  Props to @hippietrail for that part.