# What is our stance on questions on people traveling with F1 visas?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, questions

What is our stance on questions on people traveling with F1 visas? Are they on-topic or off-topic?

Sometimes they get closed, sometimes they stay open:

- [Can I travel to Boston from Bangalore with layover at London?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/161684/1810)
- [Chinese International student wanting to enter US on F-1 Visa [closed]](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/161568/1810)

I'd remark that one doesn't have to study in the US for over 6 months to need a F1.

Comment: See also *[Gap between Travel and Expatriates](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3356)* and *[Working holiday good, au pair bad, expat bad? Why not set the bar at one year regardless of purpose?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1637/)* An older discussion is *[How did temporary stays longer than a tourist visa become off-topic?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1467)* but this predates Expats.SE and has no resolution.

Answer (score 5):

I think it is not the visa on which the decision should be based but whether the person is traveling for a short time or with the intention to stay for months or longer.
Some  questions are about the journey and fit with us, even when OP intents to stay long term in the final destination.
It is not always clear from the question and we do miss questions that should have been migrated to Expatriates or closed.

If you find a question that better fits on our sister site, please flag and vote to close for that reason.

Comment: Thank you. The OP indeed often doesn't specify for how long they'll stay in the US, since this is not relevant to 99% of questions on F1. What to do if the OP doesn't specify the length of their stay in the US?

Comment: If unsure, flag and do not vote to close, or ignore.